# Return all entries not in other table and entries that match condition in other table linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this query

```
IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> aco = 
       (from  i in dbCon.nfoInventories 
        join a in dbCon.asset_status on i.asset_id equals a.asset_id
        join emp in dbCon.nfoEmployees on a.jv_id equals emp.jv_id                    
        where (a.checked_in != null)
        select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem 
        {
              asset_id = a.asset_id,  
              inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
              jvid=a.jv_id,  
              fullname = emp.fullname, 
              checked_out = a.checked_out, 
              checked_in = a.checked_in
        });
```

I also want to include inventory which is not found in the asset_status table.  Those entries would not have employee info and would return null for jv_id, fullname, checked_in and checked_out.

I've made the correct SQL query which returns the results I want.

```
select * from nfoInventory as i
left outer join asset_status a on i.asset_id = a.asset_id
left outer join nfoEmployee as e on a.jv_id = e.jv_id
where i.asset_id not in (Select asset_id from asset_status where checked_in is null)
```

But I am still unable to get it to work with Linq to Entities

I have tried

```
IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> aco = (
        from  i in dbCon.nfoInventories
        from asset in dbCon.asset_status.Where(a => a.asset_id == i.asset_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from emp in dbCon.nfoEmployees.Where(ne => ne.jv_id == asset.jv_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (asset.checked_in != null)
        select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem 
        {
              asset_id = i.asset_id,  
              inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
              jvid=a.jv_id,  
              fullname = emp.fullname, 
              checked_out = a.checked_out, 
              checked_in = a.checked_in
        });
```

But get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Lester.Model.asset_status] DefaultIfEmpty
>   [asset_status][System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Lester.Model.asset_status])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have tried

```
  IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> aco = (
          from i in dbCon.nfoInventories
          join a in dbCon.asset_status on i.asset_id equals a.asset_id
          join emp in dbCon.nfoEmployees on a.jv_id equals emp.jv_id
          where (a.checked_in != null) || !(from c in dbCon.asset_status select c.asset_id).Contains(a.asset_id)
          select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem 
        {
              asset_id = i.asset_id,  
              inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
              jvid=a.jv_id,  
              fullname = emp.fullname, 
              checked_out = a.checked_out, 
              checked_in = a.checked_in
        });
```

and get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   Contains[String][System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String],
>   System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

I've also tried

```
IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> aco = (from i in dbCon.nfoInventories
        join a in dbCon.asset_status on i.asset_id equals a.asset_id
        join emp in dbCon.nfoEmployees on a.jv_id equals emp.jv_id
        where (a.checked_in != null) || (!dbCon.asset_status.Any(c => c.asset_id == i.asset_id))
        select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem 
        {
              asset_id = i.asset_id,  
              inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
              jvid=a.jv_id,  
              fullname = emp.fullname, 
              checked_out = a.checked_out, 
              checked_in = a.checked_in
        });
```

But get the same results as my original query.  Just the assets that are checked_in, but not the assets that have never been checked out.

How can I do this?  Thanks

Comment: The thing you're looking for is a left join. There is already a ton of questions about how to perform left join using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get this working using one query.  I finally did 2 queries and unioned the results.

```
IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> returned = (from a in dbCon.asset_status
                                                   join emp in dbCon.nfoEmployees on a.jv_id equals emp.jv_id
                                                   join i in dbCon.nfoInventories on a.asset_id equals i.asset_id
                                                   where (a.checked_in != null)
                                                   select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem { 
                                                         asset_id = a.asset_id, 
                                                         inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
                                                         jvid = a.jv_id, 
                                                         fullname = emp.fullname, 
                                                         checked_out = a.checked_out,
                                                         checked_in = a.checked_in
                                                   });

IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> notcheckedout = from i in dbCon.nfoInventories
                                                        where (!dbCon.asset_status.Any(c => c.asset_id == i.asset_id))
                                                        select new Reports.AssetNotCheckOutReportItem { 
                                                                          asset_id = i.asset_id, 
                                                                          inv_desc = i.inv_desc, 
                                                                          jvid = null, 
                                                                          fullname = null, 
                                                                          checked_out = null,
                                                                          checked_in = null
                                                        };

IEnumerable<AssetNotCheckOutReportItem> assets = returned.Union(notcheckedout).OrderBy(q => q.asset_id);
```